# Java: How to implement listener to provide realtime audio stream position?

Tags: java, events, audio, synchronize

I'm working on an application to synchronize with realtime audio playback. I would like to define a listener with a specific timestep, and use the listener to get updates every time the audio being played has advanced by a timestep. Implementing this functionality must be possible (existence proof being time counter of audio player apps) but the architecture I have in mind might not be possible.

Ideally, I would listen to the audio stream on the SPEAKER or HEADPHONE Target Port of the sound card. The existing LineListener/LineEvent functionality only supports START/STOP/OPEN/CLOSE events, and I can't subclass and augment the Target Port implementation (or SourceDataLine or TargetDataLine).

How can I do this? Do I need to have a Thread constantly polling the getMicrosecondPosition() or getLongFramePosition() methods and fire my own event at the appropriate time? That sounds very inefficient. If I used a Timer to trigger the poll at regular time periods, then I'm better off than just using the system timers between the available START and STOP events that are supported on Port/DataLines. I would call the getMicrosecondPosition() method to synchronize, but I think that is likely to result in occaisional errors due to drift between the system Timer and real time audio. I'd expect to see repeats or skips of the counter (i.e. 1:23:003, 1:23:004, 1:23:006, 1:23:007... or 1:23:003, 1:23:004, 1:23:004, 1:23:005..).

I'm looking at the javazoom mp3 player source to see how they did it but no luck figuring it out so far. Any help/tips will be appreciated.

Comment: there must be a java library for this. I've used one in Qt. look on the web first before reinventing the wheel

Comment: *"Do I need to have a Thread constantly polling the getMicrosecondPosition() or getLongFramePosition() methods and fire my own event at the appropriate time? That sounds very inefficient."*  Not to me it doesn't.

Comment: @UmNyobe - yes, the javazoom player has this functionality and provides source. I'm looking there for ideas.

Comment: why do you need microseconds resolution?? Usually these library give you the position in microseconds, but don't expect to have events each 100 microseconds.

Comment: @UmNyobe - I need no finer than 1 milliscond resolution. My example was to poll the getMicrosecondPosition() method every 100 milliSeconds using a System Timer. If the value has rolled over to the next full milliSecond, only then would I fire an event for my listener. I picked 100 milliSeconds as the polling timestep to be sure that my event-firing (1 milliSecond) would be accurate to .1 milliSecond. I would not fire the event every .1 milliSecond. Still unsure if that Timer resolution is reliable across most common OSes. Hope that's clearer.